# Image in Toolbar item on iOS are white(Xamarin Forms)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, toolbar, image-size

[image]

Hi,
I have Xamarin Forms project,and in toolbar item on andorid and uwp are work fine,but on iOS are white image.Can you help me?

My xaml code:

```
ContentPage.ToolbarItems
            ToolbarItem 
                         Priority="0"
                         Order="Primary" Command="{Binding PrikaziInfoFilteriCommand}"
                ToolbarItem.Icon
                    OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
                        OnPlatform.Android
                            FileImageSource File="greenifnromation.png"
                        OnPlatform.Android

                        OnPlatform.iOS
                            FileImageSource  File="greenifnromation.png" 
                        OnPlatform.iOS
                        OnPlatform.WinPhone
                            FileImageSource File="Assets/greenifnromation.png" 
                        OnPlatform.WinPhone

                    OnPlatform
                ToolbarItem.Icon

            ToolbarItem
            ToolbarItem Icon="{Binding ImageSourceKalendarPlusMinus}"            
                         Priority="0" 
                     Order="Primary" Command="{Binding PrikaziCommand}"

            ToolbarItem
        ContentPage.ToolbarItems
```

Comment: You should create a custom renderer in IOS,please see JohnMiller's reply https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11003/navigationitem-button-with-custom-image-cant-see-image

Comment: This is not help me,he works with code behind.Need me from xaml.And what are bug here? My code behind already succeeds one class ,and cannot 2 class succeeds.Why this image on ios be blue or white color?

Answer (score 0):

iOS by default has white tinting in their ToolbarItems, which is why it doesn't hsow the way you want. Unfortunately you will have to create an iOS NavigationRenderer. Have it override NavigationPage and then add the follwoing code:

```
public override void PushViewController(UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
    {
        base.PushViewController(viewController, animated);

        var currentPage = (this.Element as Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage)?.CurrentPage;

        if (this.NavigationBar == null || currentPage == null)
            return;

        var buttonItems = TopViewController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems;

        foreach (var button in buttonItems)
        {
            button.Image = button.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
            button.TintColor = UIColor.Clear;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Overriding NavigationPage, should ensure that the images are correct throughout the app where you make use of a NavigationPage