# Xamarin iOS ToolbarItem Image showing white image

Tags: xamarin

**Xamarin Forms IconImageSource:**

On Android Toolbar image is shown correctly, on iOS a white image is shown. How can I fix this?
I added file to Resources folder and set build Action to BundleResource.

If I change filename to non excisting file, image is not shown at all. I tried changing extension to JPG, same result, also a white image is shown.

I used this code snippit.

```
        ToolbarItem toolbarItemSearch = new ToolbarItem { IconImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("searchIcon.png") };
        ToolbarItems.Add(toolbarItemSearch);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iOS has tinting the `ToolbarItems` by default , the color is blue/white .

To solve it we need to create a custom renderer for `NavigationPage` , and set the `TintColor`  to transparent , and set the image with another rendering mode .

##### Sample code

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.iOS
{
    class MyRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void PushViewController(UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
        {
            base.PushViewController(viewController, animated);

            var currentPage = (this.Element as Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage)?.CurrentPage;

            if (this.NavigationBar == null || currentPage == null)
                return;

            var buttonItems = TopViewController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems;

            foreach (var button in buttonItems)
            {
                if(button.Image != null){
                    button.Image = button.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
                    button.TintColor = UIColor.Clear;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to

[Image in Toolbar item on iOS are white(Xamarin Forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60652299/image-in-toolbar-item-on-ios-are-whitexamarin-forms)

Comment: Thanx. Can you help how to get this done? "To solve it we need to create a custom renderer for NavigationPage" Where should I put your code snippit?

Comment: Create a new class in iOS project , then copy my code into it and change the namespace ,refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: Thanx @ColeX -MSFT ! This did the trick! I only had to put in a null pointer check for non image toolbaritems: 

if(button.Image != null)

Answer (score -3):

The solution from @ColeX - MSFT did the trick! Additionally make sure to do a null pointer check for non Image buttons.

[image: Nullpointer check]

Comment: Consider marking my answer if it is helpful , I've edited the answer .